# Google Sheets - Loop through Sheets consolidating data

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets-api

I am after a bit of help looping through sheets in google.

Scenario - I have around 20 tabs all with the same layout, I need to gather information from all of them and place into 1 master sheet.
The data starts on row 2 (headers) and can be variable in length (End column if needed is column "Z" )

The code can either create a new tab to place all the data or I can create a specific tab.

(might need to take into account that I need to not include some sheets - I can define these)

In excel it would be a simple
Create new tab (Called Summary)
Loop through tabs
If tab name is not on my exceptions list then copy range on sheet (Dynamic Range)
Place range on next available row on Summary tab
Repeat until done

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has similar problems I managed to work some code out myself (might not be the quickest but it does the job)

```
function LoopSheetsMergeData(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
var destsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary");//MasterSheet To Merge To
var StartRow = 4//StartRow on all tabs
var StartCol = 1//AllData starts in Column 1  
var EndCol = 26//End Column of all data  
for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s]
    if (sheet.getName() == "Summary") //Disregard certain tabs
    {      
    }
    else
    {    
var EndRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var copyRng = sheet.getRange(StartRow,StartCol,EndRow,EndCol);
var destlastRow = destsheet.getLastRow();
var nextRow = destlastRow +1 
var shtname = sheet.getName(); 
copyRng.copyTo(destsheet.getRange(nextRow,2));//Row and Column of where to paste the information  
var newLastRow = destsheet.getLastRow();//New last Row after pasting the data
destsheet.getRange(nextRow,1,newLastRow,1).setValue(shtname&&newLastRow);//Insert into column 1 for each row copied the name of the sheet it came from      
    }
  }//end of  sheets loop.
}// end of function...
```